# How to determine substring OR match?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex that has an | (or) in it and I would like to determine what part of the or matched in the regex:

Possible Inputs:

-- Input 1 --

```
Stuff here to keep.

-- First --
all of this below
gets
deleted
```

-- Input 2 --

```
Stuff here to keep.

-- Second --
all of this below
gets
deleted
```

Regex to match part of an incoming input source and determine what part of the | (or) was matched?  "-- First --" or "-- Second --"

```
 Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)-+ *(?:First|Second) *-+", Pattern.DOTALL);
 Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
  if (m.find()) {
  // How can I tell if the regex matched "First" or "Second"?
```

}

How can I tell which input was matched (First or Second)?

Comment: In a simple case like this, you could say `(First|Second)` instead of `(?:First|Second)`, and then `m.group(2)` will be either `"First"` or `"Second"` which you could test with `.equals`.  But if the two regexes are anything other than a simple sequence of characters, this approach breaks down, and you'd want to look at Vache's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression does not contain that information. However, you could use some additional groups to figure it out.

Example pattern: `(?:(First)|(Second))`

On the string `First` the second capture group will be empty and with `Second` the first one will be empty. A simple inspection of the groups returned to Java will tell you which part of the regex matched.

EDIT: I assumed that `First` and `Second` were used as placeholders for the sake of simplicity and actually represent more complex expressions. If you are really looking to find which of two strings was matched, then having a single capture group (like this: `(First|Second)`) and comparing its content with `First` will do the job just fine.

Comment: An other way consists to use a capturing group for one part of the alternation and to test it after: `(?:(First)|Second)` (but this works only with two possibilities)

Answer (score 1):

Because RegExes are **stateless** there is no way to tell by using only one regex.
The solution is to use two different RegExes and make a case decision.

However, you can use `group()` which returns the last match as `String`.
You can test this for `.contains("First")`.

```
if(m.group().contains("First")) {
   // case 1
} else { 
   // case 2
}
```